# Is there an object model for extracting information from an XPS document?

Tags: .net, vb.net, xps

I have managed to retrieve the text from an XPS document and use it as required ([thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262197/extract-text-from-a-xps-document/12281904#12281904)), however I wondered if there was a further object related model (as opposed to using an `XmlReader`) to use that automatically puts all the elements into an object collection that you can loop in code etc.

It's a contrived example, but something like the pesudo code here:

```
    'open the xps document
    Dim xpsDoc As New XpsDocument(pathToTestXps, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
    'load the fixed document squences
    Dim fixedDocSeqReader As IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader = xpsDoc.FixedDocumentSequenceReader
    'the content will go here
    Dim sbContent As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    'loops the fixed focuments
    For Each docReader As IXpsFixedDocumentReader In fixedDocSeqReader.FixedDocuments

        'loop the fixed pages
        For Each fixedPageReader As IXpsFixedPageReader In docReader.FixedPages

'BEGIN PSEUDO CODE
            Dim content as IXpsContentCollection = fixedPageReader.Contents

            For Each contentItem as IXpsContentItem In Contents
                Select Case contentItem.Type
                    Case IXpsContentItem.ContentType.Canvas 'Group 
                        'loop content items, check their type, do stuff
                    Case IXpsContentItem.ContentType.Glyph 'Text
                         Dim str As String = DirectCast(contentItem, Glyph).UniCodeString
                         'do something with the string
                    Case IXpsContentItem.ContentType.Path 'Shape
                         'get the shape properties etc
                    Case Else
                        Throw New ApplicationException("XPS Content Type Not Expected:" & contentItem.Type.ToString)
                End Select
            Next
'END PSEUDO CODE

        Next

    Next
```

If there isn't such a model, what is the easiest way of using the XMLReader, is there a good reference for the XML elements and attributes?

For context, at the moment, I am just doing this in place of the pseudo code above:

```
            'get the xml for the fixed pages
            Dim pageContentReader As System.Xml.XmlReader = fixedPageReader.XmlReader
            While pageContentReader.Read()

                'if it is a canvas, it's a new line or some other stuff
                If pageContentReader.Name = XmlElementCanvas Then

                    'other stuff won't have attibutes
                    If pageContentReader.HasAttributes Then

                        'remove the last char as it will be an excess comma
                        If sbContent.Length > 0 Then
                            sbContent.Length = sbContent.Length - 1
                            sbContent.AppendLine()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                'if it is a glyph, it's the text we want
                If pageContentReader.Name = XmlElementGlyphs Then

                    'unsure, but it was in the example code, so we'll keep it
                    If pageContentReader.HasAttributes Then

                        'unicode string attribute has the text we want
                        If pageContentReader.GetAttribute(XmlAttribUnicodeString) IsNot Nothing Then

                            'add the text and a comma
                            sbContent.Append(pageContentReader.GetAttribute(XmlAttribUnicodeString))
                            sbContent.Append(",")
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            End While
```

Comment: I wish there was too.  But based on the documentation no.

Comment: Shame, I thought as much... I have a report that I need to scrape for data... do you know of any good documentation on how to do this?

Comment: But if you are already getting text what else do you need (expect).

Comment: I don't really, I just wondered if there was anything... the task for my project is to import the data contained in the report, so we need to apply a load of business logic to the extracted text to work out what it means, bit of a nightmare really as there are loads of nested tables and context related data.

Comment: The iFilter is in XPS Essentials Pack

Comment: @Blam, what does this do? have you got any examples or links? I googled it, but it just talks about indexing XPS documents, which I don't think is what I want.