# Reading XPS document not working

Tags: c#, xps, xpsdocument

I have been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281904/1438809) in trying to read text from an XPS document.

I have the following code:

```
        string filePath = @"C:\A.xps";
        XpsDocument _xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(filePath, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader fixedDocSeqReader = _xpsDocument.FixedDocumentSequenceReader;
```

The problem is `fixedDocSeqReader` is null.

I tried using this instead:

```
        var seq = _xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
```

But `seq` is also null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this being called from partially trusted code?

Comment: The root directory is protected in newer versions of Windows by design.  Does the code work if you create the file in a subfolder, such as your documents folder?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, I'm not sure.  I've got about 15 lines of code in a main method.  How do I check whether my code is partially trusted?

Comment: @CraigLebakken, I just tried placing the file in my documents folder, but `fixedDocSeqReader` is still null.