# How to find out which assembly to add to .Net Core 3 Preview 6 app that contains the namespace System.Windows.Xps.Packaging?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I cannot reference `System.Windows.Xps.Packaging` in *.Net Core 3 Preview 6*, although it is listed in the [Microsoft .Net Api Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.xps.packaging?view=netcore-3.0).

I am migrating a .Net 4.5 app that reads xps files, based on this stack overflow question [Extract text from a XPS Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262197/extract-text-from-a-xps-document). In .Net 4.5 I had to reference `ReachFramework` and `WindowsBase` to have `System.Windows.Xps.Packaging` available.

So my best guess is that in *.Net Core 3 Preview 6* the `System.Windows.Xps.Packaging` namespace is hidden in some assembly that is not explicitly named `System.Windows.Xps.Packaging` and is not named `ReachFramework` and `WindowsBase` anymore, but I cannot find the required assembly to be added to my *.Net Core 3 Preview 6* app.

How can I find out which assembly to add to my *.Net Core 3 Preview 6* app that contains the namespace `System.Windows.Xps.Packaging`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .Net Core 3 preview 6 the `ReachFramework` is part of WPF ([see the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/tree/ac9d1b7a6b0ee7c44fd2875a1174b820b3940619/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/ReachFramework)). If you create a new WPF project (`dotnet new wpf`) and add `using System.Windows.Xps.Packaging;` then you can insert the code from the stack overflow question you mentioned and it compiles without errors. However if you created another project type (e.g. console) it won't work.

There is an open issue on GitHub which my be of interest to you: [Cross platform support for XPS](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/470).